# Buildozer failed to execute the last command in Kivy

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, buildozer, android-sdk-manager

I'm making a simple apk using buildozer in kivy.

I tried re-installing two times android sdk ndk, but sdkmanager tools are not automatically installed.

> # Apache ANT found at /home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
>   # Android SDK found at /home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
>   # Android NDK found at /home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c
>   # Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
>   # Check application requirements
>   # Check garden requirements
>   # Compile platform
>   # Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=firstapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21'
>   # Cwd /home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
>
> [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
>
> [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>       "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>       exec code in run_globals
>     File "/home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1073, in 
>   
>       main()
>     File "/home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1067, in main
>       ToolchainCL()
>     File "/home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 576, in 
>   __init__
>       getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
>     File "/home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 144, in 
>   wrapper_func
>       user_ndk_api=self.ndk_api)
>     File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 236, in prepare_build_environment
>       avdmanager = sh.Command(join(sdk_dir, 'tools', 'bin', 'avdmanager'))
>     File "/home/shivam/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1202, in __init__
>       raise CommandNotFound(path)
>   sh.CommandNotFound: /home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager
>
> # Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=firstapp --bootstrap=sdl2 –
>   requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-
>   dir="/home/shivam/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
>
> #
>
> # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
>
> # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
>
> # Please read the full log, and search for it before
>
> # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
>
> # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2